# How to concurrently run mongo scripts

Tags: javascript, concurrency, process, fork, mongodb

How can I run

mongo myDbName script1.js

mongo myDbName script2.js

concurrently?

Is there a way to fork the execution? (I am searching for something like a --fork option
like in mongod --fork)

Thanks folks!
Olmo

Answer (score 2):

Running those two scripts is like running two commands on the shell.

Simplest thing would be to run them in two different shells. Or you can run them in background if you are not writing something important to stdout in those scripts.

In a more complex way, you can write a program which will fork and exec these two commands, but it's really an overkill.